# timer.interval C# .NET 6Hz

Tags: c#, timer

Is it possible to set the `timer.interval` to a timer in Windows Form Application to 6 Hz in some

e.g. 166,7 ms?

```
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Interval = 143;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
```

It is for my flickering buttons.

Comment: you could calculate it yourself. `(1000 / hertz)` to convert it to MS.

Comment: Set it to 167 [ms]. It will not be 6 Hz but very very close to it, impossible to tell the difference.

Comment: Which namespace is the Timer class you have used in?

Comment: Also, pro-tip for the future: Stick around when you've asked a question so you can answer any requests for clarification immediately. Most of the traffic for new questions will come right after it's asked.

Comment: _[Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))_

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply set 166.7ms ?

```
int hertz = 6;
timer1.Start();
timer1.Interval = (1000.0 / hertz);
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: _"Why don't you simply set 166.7ms ?"_ - That won't set it to `166.7ms` but most likely `167 ms` at best being that `System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Interval` is an `int`

Comment: No. That'll result in a compile time error because there's no implicit conversion from double to int.

Comment: I'm not sure Interval takes in account decimal part (even if it's a double), but that sounds to be senseful. 167ms should be a little closer of 6Hz than 166. edit :  System.Timers.Timer.Interval is a double, System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Interval is an int. Microsoft's sense of humor :)

Comment: It is better to set 166.7 as internally this is done like: (int)Math.Ceiling(this.interval) (try to disassemble this so you'll see).

Comment: @AFract  _"...but that sounds to be senseful.  167ms should be a little closer of 6Hz than 166"_ - don't forget, WinForms `Timer` is not high-resolution and even if it were it notifies via the Windows Message Pump so accuracy is already problematic

Comment: See my edit above. We're not sure of the class used by OP :). Let's suppose it's the winform one. You're right to warn about lack of precision of timer, OP should be aware of that.